# Can we use firebase with flutter just for authentication and custom server for everything else?

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, firebase-authentication

I an planning to make a social media application using flutter. I want to give the user ability to sign in using Google or Facebook accounts which can be easily done using firebase authentication but I am worried about the cost because within 2 months the number of users will be approximately 100,000. I was thinking of we could just sign up/sign in using firebase and store data and push/pull all the other requests from a hostgator server(mysql db). 
And if it is possible can I do it using just dart language or do I need some other languages too like ruby, C# it python (I am not a big fan of php)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can use Firebase **just** for authentication and your mysql db on Hostgator for everything else. Firebase auth is free (except to phone auth), as @Doug Stevenson has mentioned.

The (firebase) authentication can be done in your Flutter app. You do not need a server code to do this. Firebase auth gives back 'user' object with attributes like user name, email, profile photo url etc which you can store in your mySQL db as well (if required).

Comment: Oh wow this was exactly what I was looking for! Can you provide me links for any example of storing it into mySQL db?(if possible)

Comment: Glad it helped. See if [this](https://medium.com/developer-diary/asp-net-mvc-5-with-entity-framework-and-mysql-code-first-migrations-6e315669b6b7) link helps.

Answer (score 1):

Firebase Authentication doesn't cost anything to use for signing in with Google or Facebook accounts.  It doesn't cost any more based on the number of users you have.  You are only going to be charged if you use phone authentication past the initial free tier limits, as described on the [pricing page](https://firebase.google.com/pricing).  So I wouldn't bee too concerned about costs.

You can do all the signups in client app code.  You don't need a backend at all to use Firebase Auth, but you can bring any backend you want.

Comment: After signing user up with firebase, how can I do everything else from another server. Do I need to use a common key or what do I need to do?

Comment: You can follow the instructions for the Firebase Admin SDK. https://firebase.google.com/docs/admin/setup

Answer (score 0):

```
import 'package:express/express.dart';
import 'package:firebase_admin/firebase_admin.dart';

void main() async {
  // Initialize the Firebase Admin SDK
  await FirebaseAdmin.initializeApp(
      credential: FirebaseAdmin.ServiceAccountCredential(
          '/path/to/serviceAccountKey.json'));

  // Create a new Express app
  var app = Express();

  // Implement the API endpoint for authentication
  app.post('/login', (request, response) async {
    // Get the user's email and password from the request body
    var email = request.body['email'];
    var password = request.body['password'];

    // Verify the user's credentials using the Firebase Admin SDK
    try {
      var userRecord = await FirebaseAuth.instance
          .signInWithEmailAndPassword(email: email, password: password);

      // If the login was successful, create a new session for the user
      request.session['uid'] = userRecord.uid;

      // Return a success response
      response.send({'success': true});
    } catch (error) {
      // If the login failed, return an error response
      response.send({'success': false, 'error': error.toString()});
    }
  });

  // Start the server
  app.listen(3000);
}
```